# Tokens skip whitespace?

Tags: java, whitespace, token

Okay, I've asked another question about this that I've since solved, but here is a brief explanation of what I want to do: I want to be able to extract text from text files as tokens - for example, say I have a text file that contains the sentence:

It's a good restaurant,

believe me!

I want to extract the contents of this as 'tokens' - for example, one token would be "It's", the next token would be " ", the one after that would be "a", then " ", then "good", then "restaurant", then "," and "\n", then "believe", " ", "me", "!". So I guess one way of putting it is that tokens are either words or not words.

Here is my code so far:

```
/**
* Returns the next token, or throws a NoSuchElementException if none remain.
*/
public Token next() {
  if (c == -1) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

  Writer sw=new CharArrayWriter();
  boolean trf=false;
  try {
        while ( c != -1 && isWordCharacter(c) ) {
                sw.write(c);
                c = r.read();
                trf=true;
        }
        while ( c != -1 && !isWordCharacter(c)) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(c)&&!(trf==true)){
                sw.write(c);
                c=r.read();
                }
            else if (Character.isWhitespace(c)&&(trf==true)){
                c=r.read();
            }
            else{
                sw.write(c);
                c = r.read();

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        c = -1;
        return new Token(trf, sw.toString());
    }
    return new Token (trf, sw.toString());
}
```

The problem is that I skip whitespace, so instead of getting "It's", " ", "a", " ", "good" etc, I get "It's", "a", "good" without taking in the whitespace as tokens. Does anyone have any tips of what's wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29).
`StringTokenizer(String str, String delim, boolean returnDelims)`

As the last argument suggests, it will return the delimiters too.

`StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(sentence," \n\r",true);`

```
while(str.hasMoreTokens())
{
    System.out.println(str.nextToken());
}
```

This should give you what you want. Hope it helps.

Comment: Will it print the token along with the delimiter?

Comment: Yes it will print the delimiters too, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(sentence);
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
while(str.hasMoreTokens())
{
    //arr.add(" "); Be careful to add this only after the first word
    arr.add(str.nextToken());
}
```

Add your logic of including `" "` after every token. Its quite simple ;)

Comment: It's unnecessary to add separate logic for including tokens, stringtokenizer provides a constructor for that.